# How to test apk with different version code and small db change on emulator Android

Tags: android, testing, version, apk

I had uploaded an `apk` file on android play store and later had to make a small change in the database. I've learned that we have to change the version code and android version in order for the google store to acknowledge the new apk as an update to the previous one.

My question is, how can we test this change in an emulator? When ever I am trying to run the newly built code.

I get the following error.

```
[2012-06-11 11:44:32 - Intelsat] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2012-06-11 11:44:32 - Intelsat] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2012-06-11 11:44:32 - Intelsat] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.intelsat' in a shell.
[2012-06-11 11:44:32 - Intelsat] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 2):

The version installed on your emulator is signed with a different signature than the one you want to test. You probably have a debug version on the emulator and you are trying to install a release version (or vice versa).

Just uninstall the version on the emulator and install the one you want to test.

Comment: but i want to find out whether the change in db will occur as a result of an update. If i uninstall and then install, then ofc the my apk will function properly. Needed to know how would my application act if someone has downloaded and now an update appears.

Comment: for this you have to make sure that the signatures are the same. get an apk if your previous version, check its signature and use the same for the new version. this will allow you to update.

Answer (score 1):

According to error, it seems that you signed your apk with different signatures. In such a case, you cannot make an update, you need to do an uninstall & reinstall.

Try to sign your new apk with the same signature you used for the older one.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make the changes in `manifest.xml` file . In 'manifest.xml' file you can change the version of the application anytime you want .
          For trying the change in the emulator you can simply install an upgraded emulator (latest = 4.0.4) and check whether the application is working on it or not .